# How to customize a bitcoin rpc to show only some information (filtering out the rest)?

Tags: json-rpc

I would like to modify a bitcoin RPC, for example getblocktemplate to show only a single information, in this case: "mintime": 1594178622

I tried to go into bitcoin/src/rpc/mining.cpp

and I commented out all the info I was seeing under : static UniValue getblocktemplate(const JSONRPCRequest& request)
leaving only "mintime" and I rebuilt bitcoin, but calling getblocktemplate gave the same result with all the info...

So I'm wondering what I am doing correctly

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? This sounds like an http://xyproblem.info

Comment: I want to learn how to modify a rpc call to output the information that I want. Should I just comment out lines in the mining.cpp and rebuild or do I have anything else to do to remove that information from the output. My goal would be to acces information a little bit faster. I hope that if I ask for  one number instead of hundreds of lines of data it will be a few milliseconds faster.